# Graph Bookings API - List appointment returning empty customers array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When invoking either

```
GET /solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/calendarView
```

or

```
GET /solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/appointments
```

the returned `bookingAppointment` object has an empty customer array. However the customers appear in the UI. Any idea why this may be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Graph API.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingappointment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) the `customers` property is optional. Sometimes you have to specify optional property in `$select` statement.

```
GET solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/calendarView?start=2018-04-30T00:00:00Z&end=2018-05-10T00:00:00Z&$select=customers
```

Another option is trying `beta` version instead of `v1.0`

```
GET beta/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/calendarView?start=2018-04-30T00:00:00Z&end=2018-05-10T00:00:00Z
```